# How to test view visibility with mockito?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I want to unit test a view visibility change, but Mockito throws this error

> Must be one of: View.VISIBLE, Vie.GONE, View.INVISIBLE

This is the code for my test, `holder.entryFeedback` is a mocked object

```
verify(holder.entryTitle).setVisibility(eq(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works disabling lint inspection